# Loading a fragment within a layout-tag leads to "Error inflating class layout"

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I have created a fragment, which I incorporate within the XML of my main-activity. I like to use data-binding.

Here's the code of the main-activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/contentFragment"
            android:name="com.example.fragmentdemo2.ContentFragment" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

The code, as it is shown above, leads to an compile time-error "Error inflating class layout":

```
2021-05-22 15:13:44.828 23740-23740/com.example.fragmentdemo2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fragmentdemo2, PID: 23740
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmentdemo2/com.example.fragmentdemo2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5 in com.example.fragmentdemo2:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #5 in com.example.fragmentdemo2:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class layout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
```

If I remove the top-level -tag, then everything works perfectly fine and as expected.

**What is going wrong here? How can the "Error inflating" be fixed?**

Comment: Do you have ViewBinding enabled?

Comment: @esQmo_ That was it. Thanks a big bunch. If you like, then turn your comment into an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I can see, you're missing ViewBinding. You can enable ViewBinding/DataBinding in Gradle by setting the `viewBinding` build option to `true` in the build.gradle file as following:

```
    android {
    buildFeatures{
    viewBinding = true
    }
    }
```